# EMR Steps that should takes seconds are taking minutes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

I am running a number of very very simple steps on my EMR Cluster. One such step is creating an hbase table like such:

**step.json**

```
{
    "Name": "Create table command",
    "Type": "CUSTOM_JAR",
    "ActionOnFailure": "CONTINUE",
    "Jar": "command-runner.jar",
    "Args":
    [
        "bash",
        "-c",
        "echo create \\'myTable\\', \\'a\\' > create_table.txt; hbase shell -n create_table.txt;"
    ]
}
```

and the command should take about 0.5s to execute but the step is running for longer than 18min right now. The command has executed though. I see in the stdout logfile that it happened:

**stdout**

```
Created table factuserdatastep-echo
Took 4.8382 seconds
Hbase::Table - factuserdatastep-echo
```

And I can verify in the shell that everything is as intended. But the steps just won't terminate. The controller is stuck on this:

**controller**

```
...
INFO ProcessRunner started child process 26901
2021-12-14T15:05:45.305Z INFO HadoopJarStepRunner.Runner: startRun() called for s-34LXK66Z Child Pid: 26901
INFO Synchronously wait child process to complete : hadoop jar /var/lib/aws/emr/step-runner/hadoop-...
```

I am not sure what is taking so long does anyone have an idea why the step won't terminate?

Comment: Is `hbase shell` something that exits when done, or is it an interactive shell that stays open until you close it?

Comment: the way I run it here it just executes the command and terminates